# Php if 2 условия

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
$avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.png";
//можете нарисовать net-avatara.jpg или взять в исходниках
$result7 = mysql_query(
  "SELECT avatar,avatarthb FROM users WHERE email='$old_email'",$db
);
//извлекаем текущий аватар
$myrow7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7);
if ($myrow7['avatar'] == $ava) {
  //если аватар был стандартный, то не удаляем его,
  // ведь у нас одна картинка на всех.
  $ava = 1;
}
else {
  unlink ($myrow7['avatar']);
  unlink ($myrow7['avatarthb']);
}
//если аватар был свой, то удаляем его, затем поставим стандарт
}
?>
```

Вот он удаляет мне и *avatar* и *avatarthb*, но стандартный ставит только *avatar*, а *avatarthb* нет.

Как поставить два условия?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

наверно вот ето

```
if ($myrow7['avatar'] == $ava)
```

нада поменять на ето

```
if ($myrow7['avatar'] == $avatar)
```

тогда я ваще не понял((

$avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.png"; - это я так понимаю то что выводится у юзера если нет аватара. - и находится в поле таблицв БД  avatarthb или avatar???

Поля в  БД : avatar - это путь к файлу аватара БОЛЬШОГО.
avatarthb  - это путь к файлу аватара маленького.

$ava - это ЧТО??? $myrow7['avatar'] == $ava  - что сравниваем?

пробуй так

```
if !($myrow7['avatar'] == $avatar) 
{
//аватар не дефолтный
//удаляем файлы
unlink ($myrow7['avatar']);
unlink ($myrow7['avatarthb']);
//изменяем в базе
$result7 = mysql_query("UPDATE users avatar='$avatar', avatarthb='$avatar' WHERE  email='$old_email'",$db)
}
```

Comment: @Ale_x смотрите например пользователь загружает фото, у него загружается и большое фото и миниатюрное, если пользователь удаляет свою аватарку, то ставится вот на большое фото нет аватарки, а на уменьшенную не ставит.Мне вот нужно что бы при удалении аватарки ставилось не только большая фото но и уменьшенная копия.По этому нужно мне вот в if два условия сделать.

Comment: $ava, avatar,avatarthb  - вот ето что есть что - поясни в вопросе

Comment: @Ale_x Смотри $ava,Это заготовка  изображения нет аватарки,avatar,это сама переменная большой фотографии и avatarthb это переменная уменьшенной фотографии.

Comment: @Ale_x 
$avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.png"; - это я так понимаю то что выводится у юзера если нет аватара. - и находится в поле таблицв БД avatarthb или avatar???правильно понимаешь проблема лишь в том что если нет аватарки он в бд записывает только avatar ,а avatarthb нет.
Поля в БД : avatar - это путь к файлу аватара БОЛЬШОГО. avatarthb - это путь к файлу аватара маленького. да правильно все, 
$ava - это ЧТО??? $myrow7['avatar'] == $ava - что сравниваем?-а тут вот не $ava, а $avatar переписал.

Comment: это весь код? $ava = 1; - это тогда зачем?

Comment: @Ale_x Вот все работает,но при удалении аватарки в бд записывается только avatar то что нет картинки.Просто у меня например есть посты с уменьшеными авами, и если пользователь удалил аватарку , то аватарка уменьшенная пропадает ,а большая остается.Прости просто уже сам туплю чуть по чуть.

Comment: @Ale_x нет весь код очень огромен.